# Validate function is not triggered and form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, forms

File with the code bellow is "newrecord.html" presents the form for submitting some record entries that suppose to do the a db and after the users submits the form the validation function is called to check with it's functions the user input.
The form is loaded as normal but after the form is submitted the validation function is **not being called** and just redirects to to the "newRecord.php"

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>insert New Record</title>
    <style>
    .recordform {
border:1px solid #999999;
font: normal 14px helvetica;
color: #444444
}
</style>

    <script>
function validateAuthor(field)
{
return(field=="") ? "No Author Entered".\n" : ""
}

function validateTitle(field)
{
return(field=="") ? "No Title Entered".\n" : ""
}

function validateCategory(field)
{
return(field=="") ? "No Category Entered".\n" : ""
}

function validateYear(field)
{
if (field=="") return "No Year Entered.\n"
else if (field.length>4)
return "Enter Valid Year value (YYYY).\n"
else if (/[^0-9]/.test(field))
return "Enter only numbers 0-9"
return ""
}

function validateIsbn(field)
{
if (field=="") return "No Isbn Entered.\n"
else if (/[^0-9]/.test(field))
return "Enter only numbers"
return ""
}


function validate(form)
{
fail=validateAuthor(form.author.value)
fail+=validateTitle(form.title.value)
fail+=validateCategory(form.category.value)
fail+=validateYear(form.year.value)
fail+=validateIsbn(form.isbn.value)

if (fail==""){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(fail);
return false}
}

</script>


</head>
    <body>

<table border="0" cellpading="2" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <th colspan="2" align="center">Insert New Record</th>
    <form method="post" action="newRecord.php" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
    <tr><td>Author</td>
    <td><input type="text" maxlength="25" name="author"</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Title</td>
    <td><input type="text" maxlength="25" name="title"</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Category</td>
    <td><input type="text" maxlength="25" name="category"</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Year</td>
    <td><input type="text" maxlength="25" name="year"</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Isbn</td>
    <td><input type="text" maxlength="25" name="isbn"</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Insert New Record"></td></tr>
</form>
    </table>
        </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Check quotes carefully  `return(field=="") ? "No Author Entered".\n" : ""
`

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @Rishi thanks. It was just a stupid syntax error. After correcting the  quotes in the first 3 validation functions it worked. I just started with form validation so i new to this. Thanks for your help